# Retrieve only today records from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

In my database I stored date and time as a TIMESTAMP values. I want to retrive only today data from the database. This is code that I tried

```
$today = date("Y-m-d") . '00:00:00';
$last = date("Y-m-d") . '23:59:59';


$sql = "SELECT id, name, name2,some,some,submittimestamp,some FROM recs where submittimestamp Between $today AND $last";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

But I only get the 0 results message using this. There is more than 100 rows added today.

How can I solve this ? I cant change the database now. only way to solve this is change the PHP script

Do I need to convert PHP datetime to MYSQL timestamp ?

This is my sample database entry time-stamp value

```
2014-10-02 15:47:01
```

I only want to retrieve data for one day. time is not required !!

Comment: Maybe it's because you forgot the single space here `$today = date("Y-m-d") . ' 00:00:00';` instead of `$today = date("Y-m-d") . '00:00:00';`, Ditto for `$last`. Otherwise, that seems OK to me

Comment: Changed, but still the results are same !!

Comment: Actually I don't think the problem has to do with `PHP Datetime`, What I'd do is to take the `SQL` query you built and I'd try it into a mysql console, if the result is still 0, then you can say that problem comes from `PHP Datetime` conversion or whatever :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, name2, submittimestamp 
FROM recs WHERE submittimestamp  > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Also you  may try this, as `DATE()` ignores time part

```
SELECT id, name, name2, submittimestamp
FROM recs WHERE DATE(submittimestamp) = CURDATE();
```

Comment: hi kaka dba ...this query only show today result ??